# Chrome extensions: Content script (jQuery) in Youtube does not work properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseover

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.yt-uix-expander-arrow").attr("id", "yt-uix-expander-arrow");
    $("#yt-uix-expander-arrow").mouseover(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

injected into Youtube. Using right click > inspect element, the `<button class="yt-uix-expander-arrow">` has a `id="yt-uix-expander-arrow"` attribute successfully added to it. However the mouseover event does not trigger. However if I were to change `$("#yt-uix-expander-arrow").mouseover()` to `$(".yt-uix-expander-arrow").mouseover()` it works.

That's very unusual, because the #yt-uix-expander-arrow id has already been added to the button element. I tested it out on Facebook, adding a id to a class and doing a mouseover() event on the ID and it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more info? What exactly are you trying to do (I mean more than the obvious)? Can you provide code in a form that is more easily testable (i.e. provide the content script or at least give a url of a page you are trying to use this code on and a summary of the content script)?

Did you try just chaining them together?

```
$("button.yt-uix-expander-arrow").attr("id", "yt-uix-expander-arrow").mouseover(
    function() {
        alert("Hello");
    }
 );
```

I set up the best test I could and your code worked fine (I think, again I'm not sure EXACTLY what you're trying to do). It's hard to say what's wrong without more context.

Comment: Hi thanks, I got it already. I was careless, there are two button with the same class and I added the id to both of them. Naturally that won't work. Anyway you can find my extension here: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/abondclinmgfmldempblbaomekehgcpa/